# How to load ajax in jquery-dialogextend 2.0.4

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am trying to develop an application where user can select date and view their transaction histories in a pop up on a button clicked then an ajax will be called and return then return inside the pop.
Ref: http://romb.github.io/jquery-dialogextend/example.html

```
<div><button type="button" id="button">Button</button></div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var remoteUrl = 'send.php';
            var largeParams = {
                param1: $("#date").val()
            };
            $("#button").click(function () {
                $("#form").dialog({
                    "title": "Dialog title",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480,
                    "modal": true,
                    "resizable": true,
                    "draggable": true,
                    "dialogClass": "ui-dialog-red",
                    message: function (dialogRef) {
                        var $message = $('<div>Loading...</div>');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: remoteUrl,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: largeParams,
                            context: {
                                Dialongbox: dialogRef
                            },
                            success: function (content) {
                                this.Dialongbox.setMessage(content);
                            }
                        });

                        return $message;
                    },
                    "buttons": {"OK": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }}
                }).dialogExtend({
                    "closable": true,
                    "maximizable": true,
                    "minimizable": true,
                    "collapsable": true,
                    "dblclick": "collapse",
                    "minimizeLocation": "left",
                    "icons": {
                        "close": "ui-icon-close",
                        "maximize": "ui-icon-arrow-4-diag",
                        "minimize": "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s",
                        "collapse": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                        "restore": "ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking for help with. Please edit your post to make your question clearer; what exactly isn't working? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @lukkea I want user to click a button which will launch the pop and that pop up is ajax request.